# Wordpress admin submenus not appearing

Tags: wordpress, admin

When I log into my Wordpress site, I found few problems. The submenus of the admin area do not appear when I am hovering over a menu.

Also the Widgets area is completely messed up. Its very hard to use the widgets.

I tried adding `define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);` in my `wp-config.php` file but it does not help. I've also tried disabling all plugins and going back to the default theme.

Please help me

Comment: try to check through console in firebug or in chorme, might be some js conflict problem

Comment: Hi, Chrome gives me this: http://i.imgur.com/AjJ27pU.jpg But I don't know what it means.

Comment: It means there is javascript file in `wp-includes/charts/float/jquery.flot.selection.js` location. By default it in not included in wordpress. So fix or delete this file. Or switch to other theme.

Comment: But there is no file called this anywhere. Also no folder called charts. Also switching to another theme doesn't fix it.

Comment: it seems like something used from wordpress.com, `s0.wp.com` is `wordpress.com` url. It's hard to detect the exact problem. You can get in touch through profile.

Comment: by the way, my other site that is on the same domain hosting account also has this problem. how do i get in touch by your profile? do you mean google+?

Comment: yes, my personal email exist in my google+ profile. You can use it to contact me. Or through http://stackoverflow.com/users/790846/jogesh-pi

Comment: Hi I was having a lot of problems with my website. I just got it cleaned and now everything is fine. It was malicious code in the wp-config file. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Base on the issues, it's a jquery conflict or error on the admin area. Please deactivate the plugins one by one and see which causing the issue, you probably has admin styling plugin or something. Thanks

Cheers!

Comment: Hello, I have just tried that now and it is still not fixed. Doesn't seem like its a plugin?

Comment: How about the theme installed?, if it's still not fixed please update the wordpress version or try re-installing. Thanks!

Comment: Changing themes doesn't fix it. Updating wordpress also doesn't fix it. I cannot reinstall it, my customers will be buying. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is occur when you use wordpress from Chrome Browser. To resolve the problem, just add the following code in your **functions.php** located in theme folder.

```
function admin_menu_fix() {
echo '<style>
#adminmenu { transform: translateZ(0); }
</style>';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'admin_menu_fix');
```

For your reference: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=509179#c37